# Does measuring operator $A$ on state $|\psi\rangle$ leave the system in $A |\psi\rangle$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, measurement-problem, wavefunction-collapse

Given an observable $A$ and a system in the state represented by the vector $|\psi \rangle$, after the measurement is the system in the state $A |\psi \rangle$?

Comment: No. Why would you think so?

Comment: only if $AA=A$ in addition to $A=A^*$ and the outcome is $1$.

Comment: Possible duplicate/related to http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/280324/  in relation to the word **after**

Comment: This is a common enough misconception I knew a lecturer who dispelled it explicitly. The post-measurement state vector is a unit eigenket of $A$, but can only be predicted if $\left|\psi\right\rangle$ is such an eigenket of $A$ with non-degenerate eigenvalue, in which case the state doesn't change.

Comment: This is _the_ most common QM misconception. I think I've written at least 3 answers about this in different guises. I would love for this to become the canonical QA for that.

Comment: It was a question in my QM exam, I knew it was wrong but I was looking for an appropriate answer.

Comment: A good formalism to handle with systems after a measurement is de [density matrix formalis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Born rule, measuring $A$ could give you any of its eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ as a result, with probabilities
$$ p_i = \left| \left< \psi | a_i \right> \right|^2. $$

According to the Copenhagen interpretation the system is then found to be in the corresponding eigenstate $\left| a_i \right>$.

Comment: This is not the "Copenhagen interpretation", it's the Born rule which is an axiom of standard quantum mechanics not bound to a particular interpretation.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I agree, but the collapse of the state $\psi$ into $a_i$ is specific to the Copenhagen interpretation, which is what the question was about after all. I've made an edit.

Comment: *Collapse* is specific to the Copenhagen interpretation, but that a state "after measurement" is in an eigenstate of the measured operators is not. Where the interpretations differ whether there's a mechanism for how this eigenstate is achieved or whether it is "magical" collapse.

Comment: It depends on what kind of measurement is carried out. It can give an eigenstate or no state at all if, say, a photon is absorbed. In the latter case we can say that the system was in an eigenstate, but it is not in it and will not be in it anymore.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski Photons do not exist in QM; they only arise in QFT and in that case the state of the photon absorbed by the system is still an element in the Fock space of photon + system.

Comment: @GennaroTedesco: Then no measurement is implied. An element in the Hilbert/Fock space of photon+system is a wave function, not e result of  a measurement.

Comment: @VladimirKalitvianski I just wanted to point out that examples with photons in QM are overkill (as they lead to additional problems that are outside the scope of QM and can be confused as the real cause of something when they aren't).

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of factors you haven't considered before asking this question. 
If $\mid \psi \rangle$ is an eigenstate of the A operator, it will leave the system unchanged (upto a constant, which is the eigenvalue). If this is not the case, the wavefunction $\mid \psi \rangle$ can be represented in terms of the eigenstates of the A operator. This would look like $$\mid \psi \rangle = \sum_{} c_n\mid u_n \rangle$$, where {$\mid u_n \rangle$} is the set of basis kets. Now once the A operator acts on $\mid \psi \rangle$, the system will be left in ONE of the eigenstates (represented by $\mid u_n \rangle$) multiplied by its corresponding eigenvalue. The probability of the system 'collapsing' into a particular eigenstate of the operator is the norm squared of the coefficient of that eigenstate in the expansion above, i.e. $$Prob(\mid u_n \rangle) = \mid c_n \mid^2$$
The above come as postulates of Quantum Mechanics.

Comment: Please edit your second sentence to "..it will leave the state unchanged." Then your answer is good.